# Difference between the html result and files downloaded in jmeter sftp get function

Tags: java, get, jmeter, sftp

I am trying to load test my sftp get functionality using jmeter. I have a sftp server running on a linux box and jmeter acting as a sftp client running on another linux server. Below is the script which i am running

Script using is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.1.1 r1855137">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <kg.apc.jmeter.threads.UltimateThreadGroup guiclass="kg.apc.jmeter.threads.UltimateThreadGroupGui" testclass="kg.apc.jmeter.threads.UltimateThreadGroup" testname="jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="ultimatethreadgroupdata">
          <collectionProp name="361476282">
            <stringProp name="53">5</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="48">0</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="1572">15</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="50547">300</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="0"></stringProp>
          </collectionProp>
          <collectionProp name="639507566">
            <stringProp name="1567">10</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="1567">10</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="1629">30</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="49865">290</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="0"></stringProp>
          </collectionProp>
          <collectionProp name="1641281649">
            <stringProp name="1572">15</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="1598">20</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="1665">45</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="49834">280</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="0"></stringProp>
          </collectionProp>
          <collectionProp name="545617707">
            <stringProp name="1598">20</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="1629">30</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="1722">60</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="49803">270</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="0"></stringProp>
          </collectionProp>
          <collectionProp name="-1955907446">
            <stringProp name="1603">25</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="1660">40</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="1758">75</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="49772">260</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="0"></stringProp>
          </collectionProp>
        </collectionProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <intProp name="LoopController.loops">-1</intProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
      </kg.apc.jmeter.threads.UltimateThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <JSR223Sampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JSR223Sampler" testname="JSR223 Sampler" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="scriptLanguage">groovy</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="parameters"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="cacheKey">true</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="script">vars.put(&quot;userName&quot;,&quot;user2&quot;);
vars.put(&quot;hostIP&quot;,&quot;hostip&quot;);
vars.put(&quot;fileToGet&quot;, &quot;test_exact20m.txt&quot;);
vars.put(&quot;fileToName&quot;, &quot;test_exact20m&quot;);</stringProp>
        </JSR223Sampler>
        <hashTree/>
        <JSR223Sampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JSR223Sampler" testname="JSR223 Sampler" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="cacheKey">true</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="parameters"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="script">import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.io.*;

class Monitor implements SftpProgressMonitor {

    org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult sampleResult

    public Monitor(org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult sampleResult) {
        this.sampleResult = sampleResult
    }

    @Override
    void init(int i, String s, String s1, long l) {
    }

    @Override
    boolean count(long l) {
        sampleResult.setBytes(sampleResult.getBytes() + l)
        return true
    }

    @Override
    void end() {
    }
}

def jsch = new JSch()
def session = jsch.getSession(vars.get(&quot;userName&quot;), vars.get(&quot;hostIP&quot;), 4000) 
session.setConfig(&quot;StrictHostKeyChecking&quot;, &quot;no&quot;)
session.setPassword(&quot;user1&quot;)
def sftpSession = session.connect()
def channel = session.openChannel(&quot;sftp&quot;)
channel.connect();
def channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
log.info(&quot;SFTP Connection with host is acquired&quot; + channelSftp)
def fileName = vars.get(&quot;fileToName&quot;) + Math.random();
channelSftp.get(&quot;/XYZ/&quot; + vars.get(&quot;fileToGet&quot;), &quot;/ABC/&quot; + fileName + &quot;.txt&quot;, new Monitor(SampleResult));
log.info(&quot;FileName &quot; +fileName)
session.disconnect()</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="scriptLanguage">groovy</stringProp>
        </JSR223Sampler>
        <hashTree/>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="SimpleDataWriter" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="Simple Data Writer" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>true</subresults>
              <responseData>true</responseData>
              <samplerData>true</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>2</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
              <url>true</url>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
              <idleTime>true</idleTime>
              <connectTime>true</connectTime>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename">/DownloadMultiPart_20m_2gbHeap_75Thread_350BBPool.csv</stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

The jmx script includes **Ultimate Thread Group** also. After running the above script on linux using below command

```
nohup sh jmeter.sh -n -t DownloadMultiPart_20m_2gbHeap_75Thread_350BBPool.jmx -l DownloadMultiPart_20m_2gbHeap_75Thread_350BBPool.jtl -e -o /html &
```

The result of the nohup file shows summary = 2664 , html Dashboard report shows Samples = 2664,
But the files downloaded in the /ABC folder is 1332, the jmeter.log file shows the number of times log "SFTP Connection with host is acquired" printed is 1332 and log "FileName " printed is 1332. 
1332 Files which are downloaded are of proper size and content. I am not sure why dashboard and nohup file shows 2664 number.

I just realized after multiple testing that the result is twice the actual files downloaded.

There is no error on my sftp server side also.

Anything that i am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 JSR223 Samplers, in one you're setting the variables, and another one does actual work.

You might want to use [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables-Using-User-Defined-Variables) configuration element instead because your first JSR223 Sampler is executed by each virtual user on each iteration while it should be enough to set the variables only once.

[image]

If you want to keep the current test plan structure (i.e. for historical results compatibility) you can add [`SampleResult.setIgnore()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore--) line to the first JSR223 Sampler and it will be excluded from metrics